# $4\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+8\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1-z,$ where $z=z(x,y),\:z=\cos x,\:y=3x$ - Is my solution right?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$4\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+8\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1-z, \text{ where } z=z(x,y),\:z=\cos x,\:y=3x$$

$$\frac{dx}{4}=\frac{dy}{8}=\frac{dz}{1-z}$$

$$\frac{dx}{4}=\frac{dy}{8}\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\frac{1}{4}x=\frac{1}{8} y+C_1\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\frac{1}{4}x\:-\:\frac{1}{8}y=C_1$$

$$\frac{dx}{4}=\frac{dz}{1-z}\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\frac{1}{4}x\:=\:-\ln\left(C_2\left|1-z\right|\right)\:\:\rightarrow \:\:-\frac{1}{4} x=\ln\left(C_2\left|1-z\right|\right)\:\:\rightarrow \:\:e^{-\frac{1}{4} x} = C_2\left|1-z\right|\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-z\right|}=C_2$$

$$f\left(C_1\right)=C_2\:\:\rightarrow \:\:f\left(\frac{1}{4}x\:-\:\frac{1}{8}y\right)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-z\right|}\:\:$$

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-z\right|}\:\:=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{12}y}}{\left|1-\cos x\right|}\:\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\:\frac{1}{\left|1-z\right|}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{12}y+\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-\cos x\right|}\:\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\:\left(\text{because $e^\text{something}$ is always positive}\right)\:\:\left|\frac{1}{1-z}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{12}y+\frac{1}{4}x}}{1-\cos x}\right|\:\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\:\frac{1}{1-z}\:=\:\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{12}y+\frac{1}{4}x}}{1-\cos x}\:\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\:1-z\:=\:\frac{1-\cos x}{e^{-\frac{1}{12}y+\frac{1}{4}x}}\:\:\:\rightarrow \:\:\:z=1-\frac{1-\cos x}{e^{-\frac{1}{12}y+\frac{1}{4}x}}$$

Is this right? And if not, why so?

Comment: See my edits to this question for correct MathJax usage. In particular $\cos x$ instead of $cosx,$ $\ln x$ instead of $ln x,$ and \text{} where needed. $\qquad$

Comment: Did you verify if the found solution obeys the PDE? I found another result: $$z = 1 + e^{\frac{1}{4} (y-3 x)} (\cos (2 x-y)-1)$$

Comment: It does not obey the PDE, I've checked it, so I don't know where the mistake is here in my solution

Comment: I am also doing other exercises and it's always wrong so I think there must be a flaw in the method I use, but I don't know why there should be a flaw in the first place. I am just doing f(C1)=C2 (or f(C2)=C1 whatever is the most convenient) and then I simply calculate C2 = C2 (with initial conditions applied) which should get me a z=... solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Student :

All you did is correct up to the general solution :
$$f\left(\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{8}y\right)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-z\right|} \tag 1$$

Note that one could equivalently write :
$\quad z=1+e^{-\frac14 x}F(2x-y)\quad$
because $f$ and $F$ are arbitrary functions : Think about it !

Nevertheless, even with your over-complicated (but correct) general solution it is possible to apply the condition $z=\cos(x)$ on the curve $y=3x$ as shown below :

$$f\left(\frac{1}{4}x\:-\:\frac{1}{8}(3x)\right)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-\cos(x)\right|}$$
$$f\left(-\frac{1}{8}x\right)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-\cos(x)\right|}$$
Let $X=-\frac{1}{8}x\quad\implies\quad x=-8X$
$$f(X)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}(-8X)}}{\left|1-\cos(-8X)\right|}=\frac{e^{2X}}{\left|1-\cos(-8X)\right|}$$
Now the function $f(X)$ is known. We put it into the above general solution $(1)$ where $X=\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{8}y\quad$ and then $\quad f\left(\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{8}y\right)=\frac{e^{2\left(\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{8}y\right)}}{\left|1-\cos\left(-8\left(\frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{8}y\right)\right)\right|}=
\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}y}}{\left|1-\cos\left(-2x+y\right)\right|}$

$$\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}y}}{\left|1-\cos\left(-2x+y\right)\right|}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{4}x}}{\left|1-z\right|} \tag {from Eq.1}$$
$$\left|1-z\right|=e^{\frac14(-3x+y)}\left|1-\cos\left(-2x+y\right)\right|$$
The absolute values are eliminated with correct signs so that the condition $z=\cos(x)$ for $y=3x$ is satisfied :
$$z=1-e^{\frac14(-3x+y)}\left(1-\cos\left(-2x+y\right)\right)$$
This is a boring calculus which can be much simpler in using the general solution on the form $z=1+e^{-\frac14 x}F(2x-y)$. This was to show that the method works in the case of the form of general solution that you wrote.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. On the one hand we know what f(1/4x - 1/8y) is equal to 
(with the help of z etc.), but on the other hand, because z is dependent on x and y,  f(1/4x - 1/8y) should be also equal to something with only x and y, so we have to calculate f(x) first by using all of our known initial conditions, and then plugging 1/4x - 1/8y in. Then we are able to calculate z. Now I've understood it finally, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From

$$
\cases{
C_1 = y-2x\\
C_2 = (1-z)e^{\frac x4}}\Rightarrow C_2 = \Phi(C_1)\Rightarrow (1-z)e^{\frac x4}=\Phi(y-2x)\Rightarrow z=1-e^{-\frac x4}\Phi(y-2x)
$$

with the boundary conditions

$$
\cos x = 1-e^{-\frac x4}\Phi(x)\Rightarrow\Phi(x) = e^{\frac x4}(\cos x-1)
$$

etc.

Comment: Could you show me how you calculated phi(x)? I think it's wrong, if we multiply both sides by e^(x/4) we'll get e^(x/4)(cos(x) - 1) = -phi(-x) => e^(x/4)(-cos(x)+ 1) = phi(-x) => e^(-x/4)(-cos(-x)+ 1) = phi(x) => e^(-x/4)(-cos(x)+ 1) = phi(x)

Comment: Please. Use $y-2x$ instead $2x-y$.